# Using ASP.Net MVC Ajax and drop-down list on change

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have a partial view called _productsFilteredPartial and a dropdown list of products like

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="sel1"></label>
    <select class="form-control" id="cat">
        <option>Select From The List</option>
        @{
            DataEntities ctx = new DataEntities();
            var cat = ctx.Categories.OrderByDescending(p => p.CategoryName);
            foreach (var item in cat)
            {
                <option Value="@item.Id" >@item.Name</option>
            }
        }
    </select>
</div>
```

Now I need to update and filter the `_productsFilteredPartial` by Ajax  Ajax.BeginForm and filtering the products on change of the dropdown list based on each option value (`@item.Id`).

In the `_productsFilteredPartial` I have

```
@model IEnumerable<Example.Models.NW.Product>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Product ID</th>
        <th>Product Name</th>
        <th>Supplier ID</th>
        <th>Category ID</th>
        <th>Unit Price</th>
    </tr>
@foreach (var item in Model) {
<tr>
    <td>@item.ProductID</td>
    <td>@item.ProductName</td>
    <td>@item.SupplierID</td>
    <td>@item.CategoryID</td>
    <td>@item.UnitPrice</td>
</tr>  
}
</table>
```

I tried this

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $('#id').on('change', 'productsFilteredPartial',
      new AjaxOptions
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "Filtered-Products",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
        LoadingElementId = "loadingDisplay",

    }
    });
</script>
```

but this is more for link generation and not sure how to pass value from selected option of dropdown list to partial view. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to handle the `.change()` event, and use ajax to call a server method (passing the value of the selected option to it) and in that method return a partial view (or json) and in the success callback, update the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think your code is valid! You are mixing javascript and asp.net ajax helper methods in a wrong way!

What you should ideally do is, listen to the change event on the SELECT element and send the selected option value to server where your action method will return a partial view result for the grid.

So in your main view, you will need to include the partial view in a container div

```
<div id="grid">
 @Html.Partial("_productsFilteredPartial")
</div>
```

Now in the javascript part, you can use jQuery load method to update the grid result

```
$(function(){

   $("#cat").change(function(){
      var v=$(this).val();
      $("#grid").load('@Url.Action("FilteredProducts","Home")?cat='+v);
   });

});
```

Assuming you have an action method called FilteredProducts in HomeController which accepts the category and return a partial view result.

```
public ActionResult FilteredProducts(string cat)
{
   var result = new List<Example.Models.NW.Product>();
   // to do : Load the list of products to result
   return PartialView("_productsFilteredPartial",result);
}
```